# Calling malloc and free Inside Loop Results Heap Corruption

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, malloc, free

I'm working with OpenGL using C++ language and trying to parse 3D files. I need dynamic memory allocation for this, so, I ended up with malloc and free function (I like this rather than new delete). However, when I use malloc and free inside loop, it gives me heap corruption.

As I read here, [C Programming: malloc and free within a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463828/c-programming-malloc-and-free-within-a-loop), it is better to allocate the memory before calling the loop, reallocate it inside the loop, and then free it after the loop. Unfortunately, this still gives me heap corruption.

Now I have two codes ended up with heap corruption.

This is first code:

```
fVec2 *pVt;
fVec3 *pVe, *pVn;
fVec2 *pIndex2f;
int *pIndex;

for (int i = 0; i < iMesh; ++i) {
    fread(&iTr, sizeof (int), 1, pIn);

    pVt = (fVec2*)malloc(sizeof (fVec2) * iTr);
    pVe = (fVec3*)malloc(sizeof (fVec3) * iTr);
    pVn = (fVec3*)malloc(sizeof (fVec3) * iTr);
    pIndex = (int*)malloc(sizeof (int) * iTr);
    pIndex2f = (fVec2*)malloc(sizeof (fVec2) * iTr);

    for (int j = 0; j < pMesh->iTr; ++j) {
        pIndex[j] = 0;
        fread(&pVe[j], sizeof (fVec3), 1, pIn);
        fread(&pVn[j], sizeof (fVec3), 1, pIn);
        fread(&pVt[j], sizeof (fVec2), 1, pIn);
        fread(&pIndex[j], sizeof (int), 1, pIn);

        pIndex2f[j].x = pIndex[j];
        int iIndex = pIndex[j];
        Bone *pBone = &pModel->pBone[iIndex];

        fQuaternion Qc = Quaternion_Conjugate(pBone->qBone);
        pVe[j] = Vector_Substract(pVe[j], pBone->vBone);
        pVe[j] = Quaternion_RotateVector(pVe[j], Qc);
    }

    // OpenGL Stuff


    free(pVe);
    free(pVt);
    free(pVn);
    free(pIndex);
    free(pIndex2f);
}
```

The second code:

```
fVec2 *pVt = (fVec2*)malloc(sizeof (fVec2));
fVec3 *pVe = (fVec3*)malloc(sizeof (fVec3));
fVec3 *pVn = (fVec3*)malloc(sizeof (fVec3));
int *pIndex = (int*)malloc(sizeof (int));
fVec2 *pIndex2f = (fVec2*)malloc(sizeof (fVec2));

for (int i = 0; i < iMesh; ++i) {
    fread(&iTr, sizeof (int), 1, pIn);

    pVt = (fVec2*)realloc(pVt, sizeof (fVec2) * iTr);
    pVe = (fVec3*)realloc(pVe, sizeof (fVec3) * iTr);
    pVn = (fVec3*)realloc(pVn, sizeof (fVec3) * iTr);
    pIndex = (int*)realloc(pIndex, sizeof (int) * iTr);
    pIndex2f = (fVec2*)realloc(pIndex2f, sizeof (fVec2) * iTr);


    for (int j = 0; j < pMesh->iTr; ++j) {
        pIndex[j] = 0;
        fread(&pVe[j], sizeof (fVec3), 1, pIn);
        fread(&pVn[j], sizeof (fVec3), 1, pIn);
        fread(&pVt[j], sizeof (fVec2), 1, pIn);
        fread(&pIndex[j], sizeof (int), 1, pIn);

        pIndex2f[j].x = pIndex[j];
        int iIndex = pIndex[j];
        Bone *pBone = &pModel->pBone[iIndex];

        fQuaternion Qc = Quaternion_Conjugate(pBone->qBone);
        pVe[j] = Vector_Substract(pVe[j], pBone->vBone);
        pVe[j] = Quaternion_RotateVector(pVe[j], Qc);
    }

    // OpenGL Stuff
    ...

}

free(pVe);
free(pVt);
free(pVn);
free(pIndex);
free(pIndex2f);
```

I know realloc can fail, the safe way is to create temp variabel and realloc it. I did it and still ended up in heap corruption.
What did I do wrong? I'm curious. Thank you before

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you.  You'll need to provide actual working code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Also, what is setting iTr's value?

Comment: How do you know the heap corruption is caused by this part of the code?

Comment: Don't post tons of your code, make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Modifying the array using out of bounds index is the first problem I suggest looking into.

Comment: Most likely that you overwrite some memory in the code that you are hiding.

Comment: xaxxon: I've edited the code, iTr is a number of triangles i've read in the file.

Comment: Beta: because the breakpoint occurs there.

Comment: gnasher: yeah, i think so, but I don't  see something strange

Comment: R Sahu: I don't think it is caused by index out of bound. Victor: Thank you, I'll make it better next time

Comment: *"The breakpoint occurs there"?* You seem to be using the word "breakpoint" in a sense with which I am unfamiliar. But if you can detect exactly where the corruption occurs, then 1) I really want whatever tool you're using, and 2) you should have an easy time removing irrelevant code to produce a minimal example.